# c# java eid reader peripheral not detected

Tags: c#, java, peripherals

I'm trying to run a test wrote in C# that uses Java classes. In Java classes, I try to detect an EID card plugged in the computer. The Java code has been tested and works well but once I try to execute it from C#, it seems no EID card has been detected...

Does anybody know what might cause this ? A security trouble maybe? But I guess I should receive a clear Security exception in this case...

I use IKVM to generate the dll file containing Java classes... Any idea?